# Is the Java compiler the same that is on Linux/Windows?

Tags: java, macos, compiler-construction, cross-platform

I wrote some Java code in Ubuntu, but now I need program to run in Mac (it's not supposed to be ready product, I just want to be able to compile the source code). I just wonder, is there going to be a lot to change in code when compiling in Mac?

Comment: Software involves Swing GUI!..

Comment: Why do you imagine a lot of change for Mac? Mac/Linux both come from Unix-style kernels. Windows may be much different. However the produced (compiled) bytecode is always the same everywhere. Java Bytecode is a standard for all JVMs.

Comment: the byte code generated by Sun/Oracle compiler is the same regardless of 32-bit/64-bit or Linux/Windows. You may see subtle differences with the IBM/Eclipse compiler in the byte code but they won't impact the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the central ideas of Java is [write once, run anywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere) - in other words, you only have to write and compile the code once, and then it will run on any platform that has a JVM installed (with the correct version). So, you do not need to recompile your code at all for the Mac or for any other operating system.

Java compiles to [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) instead of native machine code. The Java virtual machine interprets and executes that bytecode, and translates it to native machine code using a [just-in-time compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) to make it run fast.

It doesn't matter that your program uses Swing - that by itself doesn't mean that it wouldn't work on a Mac.

The only reason why it wouldn't work is if you've used hard-coded operating system specific things in your code, like hardcoding Windows paths such as `C:\Program Files` etc. - those things ofcourse don't exist on Mac OS X or other operating systems than Windows.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have the right vesion of JRE installed your program should run provided that you don't have hard coded dependencies on the machine it is running on (ie. hard coded file paths, etc).

Comment: true, as long as all classes in use are from, or derived from, the built-in classes.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Right - ideally it should be a FAT jar (ie.  jar with all dependencies packaged with it).

Answer (score 4):

Don't compile anything! Just send them the jars. The local JVM will do the rest. That's how java works.

Disclaimer: If you need 3rd party library jars, you may need to ship them too or create a war file (or similar packaging) that contains the 3rd party jars you need.

Answer (score 4):

Java uses the JVM, or [Java Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_platform#Java_Virtual_Machine) to run the code you compile. As long as you're not using any weird OS-specific features in your program (like binding to non-Java libraries or running system commands), your "compiled" Java will likely run on most Java implementations.

There are more than one JVM version and more than one JVM implementation, so you *can* run into [compatibility issues](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/compatibility.html) if you don't keep this in mind.

Answer (score 3):

the bytecode will be the same after compilation; but if you used classes that aren't available on the Mac, you will have some more work to do.

Comment: I have standart environment, I'm not using any additional classes. Will that do? :S